# Switching component does not work in a PartialView - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems with the data-plugin switchery (Remark component bootstrap) that does not want to work in partialviews. The interesting thing is that if it stays inside a normal view, it works perfectly, but when placed inside a modal window (#modalGeneric) opened by a partialview, it does not work:

In a Normal View:
[image]

In a PartialView (Problem):

[image]

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.ContatoTipo.ContatoTipoViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_ContatoTipo";
}

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body container-fluid pt-10 pl-15 pr-15">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <vc:summary />
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label asp-for="Descricao" class="control-label">Descrição</label>
                        <input asp-for="Descricao" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Descricao" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="example">
                    <div class="float-left mr-20">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="inputiCheckBasicCheckboxes" data-plugin="switchery"
                               checked />
                    </div>
                    <label class="pt-3" for="inputBasicOn">On</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#mycheckbox').switchery({
        switcheryParent: $('#modalGenerica')
    });

</script>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

}
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalGenerica" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModal">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried giving an override in partialview, but it did not work. I think something is missing, or there is some problem with the script.

```
<script>
    $('#mycheckbox').switchery({
        switcheryParent: $('#modalGenerica')
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Don't you need to activate the plugin after the modal loads the content(dynamically I guess) ?

Comment: This is already happening. I had a similar problem using selectpicker, but I was directed to do this override in the partialview and it worked. The problem is that I am not able to do the same with the switchery because I do not know if it is correct to use switcheryParent in the script ....

Comment: @Master JR i cannot seem to be able to find the tag that has the id  modalGenerica. Can you try to use the same script but without the switcheryParent ?

Comment: @Nick Polideropoulos The modal "modalGenerica" ​​is in _Layout.cshtml .... The other plugins are located within the modal. Just can not make the switchery plugin work ... I think I'm having trouble setting the switcheryParent property. Does it exist? Or was it another name? I updated the post above with the modal window script

Comment: @MasterJR From the documentation here: http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/ i cannot seem to be able to find this option that you are passing. Am i looking on the wrong library ?

Comment: Exact! I was also checking this page, but I did not find anything. It is impossible not to exist a way of doing (he he he

Comment: Nick Polideropoulos I found this documentation (https://remark-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/javascript/index.html), but it should look something like this: var Switcher = Plugin.getPlugin('switchery');

var #elem = $('.switch');
var plugin= new Switcher($elem, {
    color: '#64bd63'
});
plugin.initialize();  I tried, but I can not.